# Passing data in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a java game, where i have a Tree holding some different data about the game. The root note of the tree has an int array which "describes" the game board.
Now i want to simulate possible steps this game can go from original game board to X turns ahead.
I'm doing this by passing the game Board to my SimulateTurn function.

```
public static AgentStructure SimulateTurn(int index, int[] gameTable)
```

Then i call the function like this:

```
AgentStructure localStruct = new AgentStructure();            
Tree node = new Tree("Child #"+(i-7), tree);  
localStruct = SimulateTurn(i, tree.getAgentStructure().gameTable);
node.setAgentStructure(localStruct);
tree.AddChild(node);
System.out.print("Node created\n");
```

But this changes the data in the original game Table

```
treee.getAgentStructure().gameTable
```

Why is that? I sense it's because the function SimulateTurn passing is changing the gameTable and not a copy of gameTable? But how can i change this? 
I'm really not very in to Java, but I'm forced to do it, because of school assignment. 
Any ideas?
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to have a copy of the array, you have to copy it by hand - otherwise, you pass an address of the original array to the method and every change reflects itself in the original array.

For copying an array, consult

```
Arrays.copyOf()
```

in its various forms.

## Example

```
final int[] gameTableCopy = Arrays.copyOf(gameTable, gameTable.length);
```

Comment: Thanks man. I knew it had something to do with this, but couldn't figure out a solution.